# Custom cli for codeigniter

Tags: php, linux, node.js, codeigniter, command-line-interface

(I don't know how to spacify in words)
I am using linux debian,
I have a kind knowledge of laravel,
I want to make artisan like command for codeigniter projects
I want to do like

```
mycommand create controller <controller name>
```

Comment: Check out Phil Sturgeon's awesome package for handling CLI input/output via CodeIgniter: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-cli

Comment: Check out https://github.com/piece601/Codeigniter-Pitisan - Codeigniter Command Line Tool, like Laravel Artisan, it can use command to create Controller Model View in quickly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use codeigniter and [run via cli](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html). Create a controller that only accepts cli request and you can make template in view directory where you can specify how a new controller looks like.

controller sample:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class create extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if( ! $this->input->is_cli_request())
        {
            show_404();
        }
    }

    public function controller($controller_name = '', $dir = '')
    {
        if (empty($controller_name))
        {
            echo 'Please enter controller name!';
        }
        else
        {
            if ( ! empty($dir))
            {
                $dir = '/' . trim($dir, '/');
            }

            $fullpath = APPPATH . 'controllers' . $dir . '/' . $controller_name . EXT;

            if (file_exists($fullpath))
            {
                echo 'Filename exists.';
            }
            else
            {
                if ( ! is_dir(dirname($fullpath)) )
                {
                    mkdir(dirname($fullpath), 0777, true) or die("Unable to create a directory!");
                }

                $data = array('controller_name' => $controller_name);

                $template = $this->load->view('template/controller', $data, true);

                $file = fopen($fullpath, "w") or die("Unable to create a file!");

                fwrite($file, html_entity_decode($template));

                echo $controller_name . ' created.';
            }
        }
    }

}
```

view sample:

```
&lt;?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class <?php echo $controller_name ?> extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {

    }

}
```

i put my controller under cli folder which would reside to APPPATH/controller/cli/create.php

to run this script, go to your project directory via terminal in where index.php is located

execute the ff commands:

```
php index.php cli create controller admin
```

this will create admin.php in controllers, however if you want to have it in a directory just add another parameter for directory

```
php index.php cli create controller admin backend
```

again this will create this file 'controller/backend/admin.php'